# Mirror screen with 2 different resolution displays, -with borders on larger resolution screen?

Tags: linux, xrandr, monitors, multi-monitor

Help.  The TV I'm trying to use as a monitor has overscan issues, it overscans both 1080p and 720p resolutions.  For my use, I'd rather have borders compared to a cut off screen.  I'm trying to get Linux Mint to output video to an external monitor like this.

In mirror mode:
[image]
AND still work as the primary display if the laptop is closed

Windows 10 does the above ^ fine.  But I can't get Linux Mint to preform the same way.

I tried entering in this

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --primary --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --same-as eDP1
```

but all I got was this:
[image]

So my TV still overscans the top and side portion.

**How do I get it centered? And have borders so apps and programs can't go beyond the 1366x768 resolution?**

I posted the same plea for help, with perhaps just a few more details, on the Linux help forums

Comment: Here is the link to the thread I mentioned above over at the Linux Mint forums  http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=203517

Answer (score 1):

More info:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 1366x768 --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080 --same-as eDP1
```

Then this:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --pos -277x-156
```

seems to do EXACTLY what I want. EXCEPT only with my laptop lid left open. Closing the lid seems to reset everything :( Even lifting the laptop lid again, it doesn't remember the previous setting. I have to re-enter the commands in terminal everytime *sigh*

Now if only I could figure out how to keep it working the way I want it no matter if I close my laptop or not. And no matter how many times I open and close it.

Comment: So to keep it working when you open and close the lid, look up how to hook the lid event and have it run the appropriate commands.  How to do that depends on how it's being told the lid is changing.  For the letterbox screen layout note that the framebuffer programs render to and the monitors which act as viewports to it may be sized independently.  By default they're made the same size, but you can use the --fb xrandr directive to set a specific size as you please and then use the commands you've already found to align your viewport appropriately. All this can be scripted and bound to the lid